# Dynamic array in Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I want to declare a simple array (dynamic list), one `set` function to push a string in and one `get` function which returns all the strings saved in the dynamic array.

I search a lot but not able to find this simple stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my solution, you need `experimental ABIEncoderV2` to return array of strings.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Test {

    string[] array;

    function push(string calldata _text) external {
        array.push(_text);
    }

    function get() external view returns(string[] memory) {
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I test it before deploy ?

Comment: sure, go to http://remix.ethereum.org, in `Run` tab choose Environment `JavaScript VM` and deploy for testing

Comment: Wow, amazing solution
Accepted
Thanks

Comment: Also when you will push string in array in Remix IDE, make sure that you have quotes like `"yourString"`

Comment: Warning: Experimental features are turned on. Do not use experimental features on live deployments.
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
I am getting this error while compiling the Smart Contract

Comment: yeah its warning, if you want to return whole array - its experimental feature for solidity 0.5.+ version, however you can do array `public`, and add `counter++` when you push strings, after that loop it and get whole array

Comment: The push function would not work since string[] does not have a member push().

Answer (score 4):

If, finally, you want to interact with your smart contract with tools like `web3j` (for java) or `web3js` (javascript) in an application, working with dynamic arrays is not going to work because of some bugs in those libraries.
In this case you should serialize your output array. Same applies if you have an input array.