# How to access Solidity mapping which has value of array type?

Tags: solidity

I define a state variable of mapping type, e.g. mapping(uint256 => uint256[]). I thought to make it public so that I can access it from outside of the contract. However, the compiler reports error `TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call: 1 arguments given but expected 2.`. It looks like the automatic getter of the mapping doesn't return an array.

For example, ContractB is the contract to be built,

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.6.0;

contract ContractB {
    mapping(uint256 => uint256[]) public data;

    function getData(uint256 index) public view returns(uint256[] memory) {
        return data[index];
    }

    function add(uint256 index, uint256 value) public {
        data[index].push(value);
    }
}
```

Creating a test contract to test ContractB,

```
import "remix_tests.sol"; // this import is automatically injected by Remix.
import "./ContractB.sol";

contract TestContractB {

    function testGetData () public {
        ContractB c = new ContractB();

        c.add(0, 1);
        c.add(0, 2);

        Assert.equal(c.data(0).length, 2, "should have 2 elements"); // There is error in this line
    }
}
```

I could create a function in ContractB which returns array, though.

Comment: Hi, looks like a bug, feel free to report this issue (but before check for duplicate)
https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues if so, edit your question with a github link to your issue report, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, @YegorZaremba, I'd like to report this to solidity to see if it could be improved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Solidity can't return dynamic arrays yet.

But you can get elements one by one. For this, you need to pass an index to getter:

```
contract TestContractB {

    function testGetData () public {
        ContractB c = new ContractB();

        c.add(0, 1);
        c.add(0, 2);

        // Assert.equal(c.data(0).length, 2, "should have 2 elements"); // Don't use this
        Assert.equal(c.data(0,0), 1, "First element should be 1"); 
        Assert.equal(c.data(0,1), 2, "Second element should be 2"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @ferit. I figured out that I can get elements one by one. But I'm wondering if this is a bug of solidity.

Comment: Not a bug. Just not supported yet. @sheng hu

Comment: I just added my answer about dynamic array in experimental version for this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53985923/dynamic-array-in-solidity/53986038#53986038