# I am returning an array in the contract. How do I accept it in my app.js using react and web3?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I have used truffle unbox react.

My contract -

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
contract SimpleStorage {
    
    enum Status { NotExist, Created, InTransit, PaidFor, Completed }
    
    struct Property {
        Status state;
        uint price;
        address currOwner;
    }

    Property[] public arr; 

    mapping (address => uint) balances; 

    Property public house;
    
    function registerProperty(uint _price) public {
        house = Property(Status.Created, _price,msg.sender);
        //emit NewProperty(msg.sender, _price);
    }

function get()public returns(Status, uint , address){
    return (house.state, house. price , house.currOwner);
}
}
```

---

App.js -

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SimpleStorageContract from "./contracts/SimpleStorage.json";
import getWeb3 from "./utils/getWeb3";

import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = { storageValue:"", web3: null, accounts: null, contract: null,newValue:"" };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      // Get network provider and web3 instance.
      const web3 = await getWeb3();

      // Use web3 to get the user's accounts.
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

      // Get the contract instance.
      const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
      const deployedNetwork = SimpleStorageContract.networks[networkId];
      const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
        SimpleStorageContract.abi,
        deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
      );

      // Set web3, accounts, and contract to the state, and then proceed with an
      // example of interacting with the contract's methods.
      this.setState({ web3, accounts, contract: instance }, this.runExample);
    } catch (error) {
      // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
      alert(
        `Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. Check console for details.`,
      );
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

handleChange(event){
  this.setState({newValue: event.target.value });
}


  handleSubmit = async event => {
    const { contract, accounts } = this.state;
    event.preventDefault();
    await contract.methods.registerProperty(this.state.newValue).send({ from: accounts[0] });
    const {response} = await contract.methods.get().call();
    this.setState({ storageValue: response });
  }

  runExample = async () => {
    const {contract } = this.state;

    // Stores a given value, 5 by default.
   // await contract.methods.set("").send({ from: accounts[0] });

    // Get the value from the contract to prove it worked.
    const response = await contract.methods.get().call();

    // Update state with the result.
    this.setState({ storageValue: response});
  };

  render() {
    //if (!this.state.web3) {
     // return <div>Loading Web3, accounts, and contract...</div>;
    //}
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Good to Go!</h1>
    
        <div>The stored value is: {this.state.storageValue}</div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" value ={this.state.newValue} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
      </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

If I return only a single value the code runs perfectly but for an array if I have to use a map, how do I do it? It is an array of structs, I have don't return as an array also, and return multiple values still it shows an error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213842/how-to-access-solidity-mapping-which-has-value-of-array-type

Same problem, please see my answer.

Comment: I understood that we cannot pass an array now I am returning three values, how do I accept it in app.js @ferit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access Solidity mapping which has value of array type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213842/how-to-access-solidity-mapping-which-has-value-of-array-type)