# How to create a dynamic memory array in Solidity?

Tags: arrays, ethereum, solidity, dynamic-arrays

I'm creating an ERC777 from a contract and I'm having trouble with the default operators. My code compiles fine but when I try to deploy it it doesn't work.

Here's a simplified version of my code

```
contract Amacoin is ERC777 {
  address public amaclicker;

  constructor(address[] memory defaultOperators) ERC777("Amacoin", "AMAC", defaultOperators) {
    amaclicker = defaultOperators[0];
  }
}

contract Amaclicker {
  Amacoin public amacoin;

  constructor() {
    address[] memory defaultOperators;
    defaultOperators[0] = address(this);
    amacoin = new Amacoin(defaultOperators);
  }
}
```

From my testing, it's the `defaultOperators[0] = address(this);` that doesn't work. Also just putting `[address(this)]` as the argument for Amacoin or defaultOperators doesn't work.

Edit: I still haven't found a solution but a workaround I've done is create a state variable and then delete it after creating Amacoin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic array in Solidity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53985923/dynamic-array-in-solidity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way. This should work.

```
address[] memory defaultOperators = new address[](1);
defaultOperators[0] = address(this);
```

Comment: This doesn't work `TypeError: Member "push" is not available in address[] memory outside of storage.`

Comment: I have modified the answer. Check this one. @kowasaur

Comment: But actually, this is not a dynamic array. As far as I know, the dynamic array is an array that is resizable i.e. has a `push` function. The mentioned here is not resizable. It's simply a declaration of static array with one element (n-elements) inside it. It is indeed a "dynamically allocated array" but NOT a "dynamic array".

Comment: What you can do though is forcefully obtain the outcome element count (even if this means looping twice – that still would not require paying for gas). This way you can declare the array after the first go and initialise its elements in the second go.

Answer (score 1):

From your question,It's simply not possible to create a dynamic memory array in solidity.